# Excel Value error on VBA line-break code

Tags: vba, excel

So I've been trying to create a program that will take a block of text and edit it to only include up to 50 characters per line, but also keeping words together (so substituting the last space in a line of text 50 characters long for a line break character) but I continue to get a value error as my output!

## Here is the code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function LnBrk50(selection) As String

    Dim bookmark As Long
    Dim step As Byte
    Dim length As Byte

'finds the last instance number of a space character in the text block within 50 characters
    length = 50 - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Left(selection, 50), " ", ""))
'replaces the last instance of a space character with a line break character
        selection = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(selection, " ", vbNewLine, length), selection)
'character number of the last line break in the text block
    bookmark = WorksheetFunction.Find(vbNewLine, selection)

    step = 0
    Do Until step = 9
'finds the last instance number of a space character in the text block within the 50 characters after the last line break
        length = 50 + bookmark - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Left(selection, 50 + bookmark), " ", ""))
'replaces the space character found in last line with a line break character
        selection = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(selection, " ", vbNewLine, length), selection)
'adds character number of the last line break
        bookmark = WorksheetFunction.Find(vbNewLine, selection, bookmark + 1)
        step = step + 1
    Loop

End Function
```

So if anyone could find what error I might be making that would produce a #VALUE! error when used on a single referenced text cell, it would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Several comments about your code: Try not to use worksheet functions when the VBA text processing functions will work better; You are using a function but not returning a value; A function called from the worksheet should provide a value that is displayed in the cell it is called from - it should not try to modify other cells.

Comment: Ah, see I thought the program would display the final output of the Do loop in the cell I use the function. As I am new to VBA I didn't see that I needed to set the function itself equal to an output. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This screenshot shows a very long text string in cell A1. Cell A2 contains

```
=LnBrk50(A1)
```

[image]

The following code is what is behind LnBrk50.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function LnBrk50(ByRef selection As Variant) As String

    Dim tempStr As String
    Dim iLoc As Long, iEnd As Long

    tempStr = selection.Value
    If Len(tempStr) > 50 Then
        iLoc = 0
        Do While Len(tempStr) - iLoc > 50
            iEnd = iLoc + 50
            If Len(tempStr) < iEnd Then iEnd = Len(tempStr)
            If Not InStrRev(tempStr, " ", iEnd) > 0 Then
                iLoc = iLoc + 1
            Else
                iLoc = InStrRev(tempStr, " ", iEnd)
                tempStr = Left(tempStr, iLoc - 1) & vbNewLine & Right(tempStr, Len(tempStr) - iLoc)
            End If
        Loop
    End If
    LnBrk50 = tempStr

End Function
```

If you would like to modify A1 instead of moving the modified text to B1, I would recommend using a subroutine and attaching it to a button instead of using a function.

Comment: Awesome! I love the Do loop you used to check for the spaces rather than using the worksheet functions! And moving it to the next column over is perfect since I need to be able to refer to ByRef from another sheet!

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Function LnBrk50(rng As Range, maxChar As Long) As String

Dim strng2 As String, subStrng As String
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long

arr = Split(rng)    
i = 0
Do While i < UBound(arr)
    subStrng = arr(i)
    Do While Len(subStrng) + 1 + Len(arr(i + 1)) <= maxChar
        subStrng = subStrng + " " + arr(i + 1)
        i = i + 1
        If i = UBound(arr) Then Exit Do
    Loop
    strng2 = strng2 & subStrng & IIf(i < UBound(arr), vbCrLf, "")
    i = i + 1
Loop    
LnBrk50 = strng2

End Function
```

where your function would be called as

```
=LnBrk50(A1,50)
```

could be interesting which is the fastest...